# hiphop for php: Issue running: ...Assertion 'threadCount >= 1' failed

Tags: php, facebook, ubuntu, hiphop

I followed all the steps for installing and building in
Ubuntu 11.04, and then when I was about running it:

> hphp/hphp test.php
>
> hphp: home/user/dev/hiphop-php/src/util/job_queue.h:306:
>   HPHP::JobQueueDispatcher::JobQueueDispatcher(int, bool,
>   int, bool, void*, bool) [with TJob = OutputJob*, TWorker =
>   OutputWorker]: Assertion `threadCount >= 1' failed.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify both paths, to hphp and to test.php as absolute paths. in my case, this solved the error.